# Can't run cloak server on Openshift ( require('http').createServer(); don't work)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, openshift

I am trying to run cloak server on Openshift. I found out, that there is a call in socket.io which does absolutely nothing on Openshift, while on local machine, it works alright.

Problem is right there:

```
require('http').createServer();
```

This call should generate server object, but it just do nothing, and I have no idea why.

Do you guys have any idea?

BTW, port selection should be OK, I am using Openshifts environmental variable.

Comment: Can you add link to repository to a clock plugin and bigger snippets ?

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you install handler to `createServer()`? Can you post some runnable code?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the reason this is not working is because when you require().createServer, you only call it once. That is the that your object is only created once, and not called on subsequent attempts.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make much sense - can you explain more fully? I think the questioner is trying to figure our how come the code works on his local machine but not when hosted in an OpenShift env. Questioner says "while on local machine, it works alright"

Comment: I lapsed to address that part. no less, Have you installed all dependencies on the OpenShift env (i.e via the package manager you are using)?